# Polar Axes Radians

Tags: tikz-pgf, polarplot

You can see from this example (found online) I have a radius of 1. Is there a way to increase the radius to four or five? I am trying to make a template for my students to graph on.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
 
\pgfplotsset{my style polar/.append style={xticklabels={,,
$\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$,
$\frac{5\pi}{6}$, $\pi$, $\frac{7\pi}{6}$, $\frac{4\pi}{3}$,
$\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\frac{5\pi}{3}$,$\frac{11\pi}{6}$,}, thick }}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[my style polar]
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I tried looking the PGFPlots manual in 5.10, but I didn't see how they were able to change the radius unless I had a graph.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: Do not use the `minimal` class. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{my style polar/.append style={xticklabels={,,
$\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$,
$\frac{5\pi}{6}$, $\pi$, $\frac{7\pi}{6}$, $\frac{4\pi}{3}$,
$\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\frac{5\pi}{3}$,$\frac{11\pi}{6}$,}, thick }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[my style polar, ymax=4]
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Polar circle diagram]

Comment: I was able to remove the y label, but is there anyway to make the dark horizontal line match the rest? I don't want it to stick out.

Comment: Add this option: `y axis line style={draw=none}`

Comment: works perfectly! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to recall your style AND ADD ONE FUNCTION TO PLOT.
The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{my style polar/.append style={xticklabels={,,
            $\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$,
            $\frac{5\pi}{6}$, $\pi$, $\frac{7\pi}{6}$, $\frac{4\pi}{3}$,
            $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\frac{5\pi}{3}$,$\frac{11\pi}{6}$,}, thick }}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{polaraxis}[xmin=0,xmax=360,
            domain=0:360,
            my style polar,
            no markers]
            \addplot +[orange, very thick, smooth] {3*cos(6*x)+2*sin(3*x)};
        \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]